# How to pass username in affiliate link in wordpress website

Tags: php, url-rewriting, parameter

I need to pass current logged in user in wordpress website as SUBID in the affiliate link as follows.

Affiliate link format is like below.

```
https://affiliatenetwork.com/track?id=myuserid&url=https://nike.com&subid={subid}
```

I want to pass current logged in user as a subid in above link. I have written below code in functions.php.

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() )
{
    $userName = get_current_user_id();
}
<----Need code here to pass $userName as subid ( mentioned in above link).------>
```

Please help.

Comment: Are you looking for [`wp_get_current_user()`]](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/)? That will get the current [`WP_User`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/), from which you can pull the user ID, the username, email address, etc.

Comment: thanks a lot. How to pass this username as a dynamic parameter in the affiliate link?

Comment: How are you generating the affiliate link?

Comment: I am generating affiliate link from affiliate network platform where there is a provision of adding dynamic parameter as sub_id. then i am pasting it on my wordpress website as a clickable link. I am trying to fetch user_id with the help of wp_get_current_user_id. But i am struggling to pass this user_id to the affiliate link. Need help in passing the user_id as subid. thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have any code that you're having trouble with, please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/405388/edit) to include it. It'll help us try to solve your problem.

Comment: I have edited my question with incomplete code. Thanks.

Comment: You say: *then i am pasting it on my wordpress website as a clickable link*. Where in your site are you pasting this? Is it on a particular page, in a post's custom field, ...?

Comment: My website is a cashback website. I have generated separate affiliate links for each brands like ( nike, adidas, reebok etc) and pasted the respective links in clickable banners for each brand. Now i want my affiliate network to fetch user details so i need to pass user_id as subid. Please do let me know for further details Thanks.

Comment: If you're using a plugin to create the banners, your best bet would be to contact that plugin's support team for assistance. If you're pasting them into a page's or a post's content, you can use the [`the_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/) filter and [`str_replace()`](https://www.php.net/str_replace) to replace the `{subid}` string with the user's ID.

Comment: thanks a lot. I will try this....

Answer (score 0):

This code adds the subid parameter if does not exist to the current URL.
Use this plugin to insert the php code:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/my-custom-functions/

But you need to use add_action() to call this function somewhere.

```
function my_change_url() {
    global $wp;
    $current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array($_GET), $wp->request));
    if ( empty($_GET['subid']) ) {
        $cuser = wp_get_current_user();
        $username = $cuser->user_login;
        $current_url = add_query_arg(array($_GET), $wp->request);
        $current_url = add_query_arg('subid', $username);
        $current_url = home_url($current_url);
    }
    return($current_url);
}
```

OR
You may use a shortcode:

```
add_shortcode('affiliate_subid', 'my_change_url');
```

Put the short code anywhere on a page:

```
[affiliate_subid]
```

Comment: This looks like it's returning an URL so it wouldn't be an add action, would it? You'd need something to emit the URL into the page, so maybe a shortcode or some other filter that echos it.

Comment: Yeah, if you want to print on an uneditable page (e.g. woocommerce pages) you have to use add_action() to the specific hook, but I added the shortcode code to the example to print the link on a page, post etc.